# Search questions by number of votes of the answers

Tags: support, search

Is possible to search for questions and sort them by the votes of the most voted **answer** (not the question)?

Comment: Yeeeeeeeep: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60367/most-upvoted-answers

Comment: Thanks Matt, I will try to modify it for matching a tag or string too. I think this should be available in StackOverflow directly, there are really good answer that are even better than many tutorials. So maybe you don't have a question, or you are not searching for a problem, you just want to learn! and read a good tutorial. Searching the most voted answers for some topic will give us a list of really good "tutorials" or "must read" things.

Comment: \@Enrique: To be honest, you should find, for the majority of cases at least, that high votes answers *will* be inside high voted questions.

Comment: Yes, there's a relation, but not as straight, take this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260134/optimizing-kohana-based-websites-for-speed-and-scalability Question: 51, Answer: 152 (that answer was the motivation for requesting this feature) Take this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp Question: 232, Answer: 141.

Comment: @Matt There are a few exceptions though.  I just wrote this query: [Low score questions with a high score answer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60642/low-scoring-questions-with-a-high-scoring-answer).  These are pretty good!

Comment: @enrique any luck with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, one way to do it would be to add `is:answer` to the front of your search, then click on the "votes" tab to order by votes.

For example, to search for the highest voted answers concerning "garbage", you could do this:

```
is:answer garbage
```

Then click the "votes" tab on the search results page.

(FYI: according to the above search, Eric Lippert has the [highest voted garbage answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794) =P)

Comment: yes !! thanks @jadarnel27, that was exactly what I was looking for :D

Comment: @Enrique Glad I could help!

Comment: That answer probably shows up as highest-voted for a lot of keywords ;)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Haha, good point.  I just thought "garbage" was the funniest (although "explosion" and "football" were a close second and third).